# C++ memset() memory overflow

Tags: buffer-overflow, memory, c++

I am new to C++.

Can any C++ expert tell me would this causing buffer overflow?

Sample Code:

```
MyObject op;
memset(&op, 0, sizeof(MyObject));
```

On my view it is ok to be this since the limit is the size of the object type itself but there is a security tools caught this as a buffer overflow. If it is really a buffer overflow, can you please describe a bit how could it be. Thank you for your clarification and explanation.

Comment: Which security tools are you using?

Comment: Come now, who voted this as off-topic? It's about the security of a particular operation in code. If that's not security, I don't know what is. Get some itch cream for your trigger finger.

Comment: It's about programming, and as the quality of answers so far shows, it would be much better handled over on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Mark It's absolutely on topic here. Whether someone could answer it better elsewhere is irrelevant. In these situations you can advise OP to ask over on another site, because they'd have better expertise, but that's not a valid reason alone to flag something to be closed as off-topic.

Comment: I also wonder if it is a false positive, but I cannot confirm it, cause I not familiar with c++. I am not sure the behavior of sizeof() and memset() in c++, I wonder whether is there anything will affect the size of the MyObject because I read this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member). Will the variables of the Object has discontinuous memory address?

Answer (score 3):

This is *not* a buffer overflow.
The buffer size you are giving to `memset` is exactly the actual size of the buffer (in this case, the object `op`).

If this is a C++ object with virtual functions, then the `memset` will zero memory that should not have been zeroed, and the call to the destructor is likely to blow up.
But this would be memory corruption, not a buffer overflow.

---

As for the reason that your tool complains:
there is a common idiom that uses the type of `memset`'s first argument to determine the buffer size:

```
memset(&my_object, 0, sizeof(my_object));
memset(my_pointer, 0, sizeof(*my_pointer));
memset(my_array, 0, sizeof(my_array));
```

It's possible that your tool throws a warning whenever you use anything else for the size, because you might forget to update the `sizeof` when you later change the actual object.

Comment: It could be that the tool in use considers clobbering the virtual function table to be an overflow, but without knowing which tool is involved, it's impossible to say.

Answer (score 1):

**Ignore me, I'm an idiot.**

Mark points out that `MyObject op` is a local-scope instantiation of a class, which will be placed on the stack. This means that `&op` is actually the address of the class data in memory.

As such, I have no idea why this was flagged. False positive, maybe?

---

<strike>It's right to complain, so let's take a look at this code. What does it do?</strike>

```
MyObject op;
```

In line 1, you define an object variable. However, you don't call its constructor, so this object variable isn't actually set to anything - right now it's just an uninitialised pointer.

```
memset(&op, 0, sizeof(MyObject));
```

In line 2, you take the address *of the variable* and and perform a `memset` at that address with a size that's almost certainly going to be larger than the size of a pointer. Take care to note that you *aren't* overwriting the memory that will contain the object's data, but rather the scope-local storage space that's used to hold a pointer to the object. This is definitely an overflow condition.

Comment: Wrong on all counts.  The first line creates an object, allocating a suitable amount of memory for it (most likely on the stack), and calls its default constructor.  The second line takes the address of that object, and fills the memory allocated for the object with zeroes.

Comment: @Mark Admittedly I've not used C++ for a while (I'm more used to C), but my understanding was that `MyObject op;` alone didn't call the default constructor, whereas `MyObject op();` does. Also, surely `&op` doesn't refer to the object itself (since `op` is a pointer type) but rather the address of the pointer?

Comment: `MyObject op;` creates an object of type `MyObject`.  `MyObject *op;` creates a pointer to an object of type `MyObject`.

Comment: @Mark Ah, yes, so it does - it's a local scope instance. Blame my lack of coffee this morning! Rather odd that this is flagged, then.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the definition of `MyObject`. Since it's C++, the constructor has set up the initial values which you then overwrite using `memset`. The destructor will assume you have not overwritten the object, and could exhibit all kinds of unintended behavior.

But since you don't show any of that code, we have to assume the worst. Memory overflows are quite possible.